# What is the bandgap value of SiO2?

Tags: spectroscopy, nanotechnology

Using Diffuse Reflectance Spectroscopy, I have obtained the band gap for $\small\ce{SiO2}$ (purchased from a chemical retailer) in the range of 3.25 to 4.75 eV.

I would like to know if the values are in the right ballpark and, if not, would like to review the DRS procedure that I carried out.  I would also like to know if the band gap determined through DRS would have such a wide range.

Comment: there are several polymorphic modifications of SiO2, that have different gaps. Most stable alfa-quartz has ~9 ev band gap according to quickly found article http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.bbr.2011.03.031 . Which one you mean?

Comment: @permeakra The DOI links to a document in "Behavioural Brain Research" ;)

Comment: @KlausWarzecha try this http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/16.870550 . Sorry

Comment: @permeakra No need to be sorry. It was just a funny coincidence.

Answer (score 4):

For thermally grown amorphous $\ce{SiO2}$ films, a bandgap of 9.3 eV was measured by [Weinberg](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.19.3107).

Measurements on $\alpha$-quartz by [Calabrese](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.18.2888) give $E_g(\Gamma)$ = 6.3 eV, compared to 9.2 eV calculated by [Chelikowsky and Schlüter](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.15.4020).

Calculations by [Ramos](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.69.085102) on $\beta$-cristobalite with the space groups $Fd3m$ (face-centred cubic, fcc), $I\bar{4}2c$ (body-centred tetragonal, bt), and $P2_13$ (simple cubic, sc) gave direct bandgaps of $E_g(\Gamma)$ = 5.48, 5.79 and 5.73 eV, respectively.